# guidelines for multi user, multi session, multi tab, cookie environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, architecture

Our current application is working fine but when you try to misbehave like we found out that When login with same user in multiple tab with different organization(there is a organization dropdown in the master page which sets the cookie whenever it is changed.)

in tab one it is org 1 and tab 2 it is org2 , cookie has the **later** org 2 in it but when we go back in tab1(which had org1) and save the record **org 2 will be saved with the record**

So can some one share some sort of a checklist with us which address these types of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not much you could do about this. Browsers share cookies between tabs. And forms authentication uses cookies to track users. That's the same behavior you will get with other sites as well such as gmail for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can add hidden field with data for recognize each view.
you store all data in server side such as session,cache,Database and serve "unique" view

Answer (score 0):

I hope you'll find an elegant solution to this problem, but AFAK one instance of browser simply shares one identity.

To deal with this situation we use HIDDEN on master page, that is a part of main form. Its value is randomly generated when first page loads. Later, the value is kept between requests. Session values are stored with HashTable key of hidden value.

2 more hacks needed to get it work.

1. Response.Redirect is done with simple form that uses POST method to pass HIDDEN value to the new page.
2. All hrefs clicked with left button also posting HIDDEN value (if user uses 'Open in new TAB/Window' direct redirect without post simply creates new HIDDEN value - new subsession.)